# Intermittently cannot scroll full page in Responsive site

Tags: iphone, ipad, responsive-design

On load of a responsive page on an iphone or ipad, maybe one out of every five times the page will scroll most of the way down and then stop. It's as if the page content is ending. If I refresh the page or reorient the device, this then allows me to scroll the rest of the way.

My viewport tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0">
```

I've gotten this on an ipad2, iphone 4 and 4s both on ios6.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Is there inline javascript happening? Like a twitter widget or something that needs to talk to a 3rd party? I had similar problems on a site where it wouldn't let me scroll down until it had loaded the twitter widget js file.

Comment: Please give a url to see the problem.